# How to test send email in Blazor server in local machine connected to Internet

Tags: blazor-server-side

Hi newbie for blazor Server. I have created a blazor server app but I need email service. I could not find any link regarding how Blazor send email. I did the following but I am not sure how to test sending email in local machine connected to internet. I tried to send but it didnot send. Need help on this.

1) Have installed mailkit nuget

2) created a class , named it MServices.

this MServices also used for other purpose such as handling Database with DbContext

2.1) add a send email method in this class

```
  public async Task<String> SendEmail()
        {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();

            MailboxAddress from = new MailboxAddress("Admin", "xxx@gmail.com");
            message.From.Add(from);

            MailboxAddress to = new MailboxAddress("User", "www@live.com");
            message.To.Add(to);

            message.Subject = "This is email subject";


            BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
            bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
            bodyBuilder.TextBody = "Hello World!";

            message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, true);
            client.Authenticate("John", "xxxxxxx");


            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
            client.Dispose();

            return "OK";
        }
```

2.2)   add this class in  configureServices of StartUp :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddScoped<MServices>();

     ...

  }
```

3) created a Razor component, named it Services.razor

Inject the above MServices into this Razor

@inject Myapp.Services.MService mservice

in Code Section:  I added the following for handling buttn click

```
  protected async Task Send()
  {
    var msg = await mservices.SendEmail()
   }
```

Would appreciate if you can help to provide the correct way to send using blazor server or a sample link to learn from.

Thanks